# In SwiftUI, is it possible to use a modifier only for a certain os target?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, target, modifier

Good day! In SwiftUI, is it possible to use a modifier only for a certain os target?
In the following code I would like to use the modifier .listStyle(SidebarListStyle()) only for the MacOS target because it does not exist for the iOS target. Thanks for you help.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var selection: Int?

  var body: some View {

    HStack() {
      NavigationView {
        List () {
          NavigationLink(destination: FirstView(), tag: 0, selection: self.$selection) {
            Text("Click Me To Display The First View")
          } // End Navigation Link

          NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), tag: 1, selection: self.$selection) {
            Text("Click Me To Display The Second View")
          } // End Navigation Link

        } // End list
        .frame(minWidth: 350, maxWidth: 350)
        .onAppear {
            self.selection = 0
        }

      } // End NavigationView
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

    } // End HStack
  } // End some View
} // End ContentView

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try using `#if os(OSX)`? [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065017/how-to-determine-device-type-from-swift-os-x-or-ios)

Comment: Yes I try using #is os(macOS) around the modifier itself but a error message appears: "Unexpected platform condition (expected 'os', 'arch', or 'swift')" ... I will try to do it around the HStack.

Comment: Wild8x, just replace ".listStyle(SidebarListStyle())" with ".navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle()) " to achieve what you're after. See also my other comment.

Comment: Thanks Workingdog. I have just tried it and it is fine! Finally!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your better off doing this:

```
 import SwiftUI

 struct ContentView: View {

@State var selection: Int?

var body: some View {
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    return theList.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    #else
    return theList.navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
    #endif
}

 var theList: some View {
 HStack() {
   NavigationView {
     List () {
       NavigationLink(destination: FirstView(), tag: 0, selection: self.$selection) {
         Text("Click Me To Display The First View")
       } // End Navigation Link

       NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), tag: 1, selection: self.$selection) {
         Text("Click Me To Display The Second View")
       } // End Navigation Link

     } // End list
     .frame(minWidth: 350, maxWidth: 350)
     .onAppear {
         self.selection = 0
     }

   } // End NavigationView
     .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

 } // End HStack
 } // End some View
 } // End ContentView
 }
```

Comment: But by doing this don't you think that the modifier will be around the HStack instead of around the NavigationView as it was originaly?

Comment: it will propagate to the NavigationView.

Answer (score 20):

You can create a `View` extension and use it like this:

```swift
List {
    // ...
}
.ifOS(.macOS) {
    $0.listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
}
```

Here's the implementation:

````swift
enum OperatingSystem {
    case macOS
    case iOS
    case tvOS
    case watchOS

    #if os(macOS)
    static let current = macOS
    #elseif os(iOS)
    static let current = iOS
    #elseif os(tvOS)
    static let current = tvOS
    #elseif os(watchOS)
    static let current = watchOS
    #else
    #error("Unsupported platform")
    #endif
}

extension View {
    /**
    Conditionally apply modifiers depending on the target operating system.

    ```
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("Unicorn")
                .font(.system(size: 10))
                .ifOS(.macOS, .tvOS) {
                    $0.font(.system(size: 20))
                }
        }
    }
    ```
    */
    @ViewBuilder
    func ifOS<Content: View>(
        _ operatingSystems: OperatingSystem...,
        modifier: (Self) -> Content
    ) -> some View {
        if operatingSystems.contains(OperatingSystem.current) {
            modifier(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
````

**However**, this will not work if you try to use a method that is not available for all the platforms you target. The only way to make that work is to use `#if os(…)` directly.

I have an extension that makes it easier to do that:

````swift
extension View {
    /**
    Modify the view in a closure. This can be useful when you need to conditionally apply a modifier that is unavailable on certain platforms.

    For example, imagine this code needing to run on macOS too where `View#actionSheet()` is not available:

    ```
    struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
            Text("Unicorn")
                .modify {
                    #if os(iOS)
                    $0.actionSheet(…)
                    #else
                    $0
                    #endif
                }
        }
    }
    ```
    */
    func modify<T: View>(@ViewBuilder modifier: (Self) -> T) -> T {
        modifier(self)
    }
}
````

Comment: Thank you so much Sindre for your reply. I will test it soon. Finally, for the moment I took the decision to do only independent Apps to avoid the mess of having plenty "if OS" statements ... but I am sure it will help others.

Comment: This works whenever the modifier is available in multiple OS.
Compiler error in some cases where the modifier statement is not available in some OS.

Example: StackNavigationViewStyle is not available in macOS

.ifOS(.iOS) {
    $0.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
}       

Compiler error: 'StackNavigationViewStyle' is unavailable in macOS

Comment: If you have some special method for platform use group for wrap : 

            .platform(.iOS) { view in
                return Group {
                    #if os(iOS)
                    view.background(Color(viewModel.colorName))
                        .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 1.5)
                    #else
                    view
                    #endif
                }
            }

Comment: The `@escaping` can be removed from the `ifOS` call, it is not actually escaping.

You can do the `modify` like that to avoid the AnyView: `func modify<T: View>(@ViewBuilder modifier: ( Self ) -> T) -> T { modifier(self) }`. The `nil` is not necessary, just return $0 if no modifications are wanted.

Comment: @hnh Good catch with the moot `@escaping`. I have your version of `modify` in my projects too, but it's less flexible as it requires you to be in a `@ViewBuilder` context, which has a lot of limitations, like no `guard`. But yours is indeed better in most cases.

Answer (score 12):

## Swift 5.5

From the Swift 5.5 version, you can use add conditions directly to the withing modifier.

```
  } // End NavigationView
    #if os(macOS)
    .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    #else
    .navigationViewStyle(DefaultNavigationViewStyle())
    #endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks DoesData for giving me the direction.

The solution was to use #is os(macOS) around the entire code and not only around the modifier itself.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var selection: Int?

  var body: some View {

    #if os(macOS)
    HStack() {
      NavigationView {
        List () {
          NavigationLink(destination: FirstView(), tag: 0, selection: self.$selection) {
            Text("Click Me To Display The First View")
          } // End Navigation Link

          NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), tag: 1, selection: self.$selection) {
            Text("Click Me To Display The Second View")
          } // End Navigation Link

        } // End list
          .frame(minWidth: 350, maxWidth: 350)
          .onAppear {
            self.selection = 0
        }

      } // End NavigationView
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    } // End HStack

    #elseif os(iOS)
    HStack() {
      NavigationView {
        List () {
          NavigationLink(destination: FirstView(), tag: 0, selection: self.$selection) {
            Text("Click Me To Display The First View")
          } // End Navigation Link

          NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(), tag: 1, selection: self.$selection) {
            Text("Click Me To Display The Second View")
          } // End Navigation Link

        } // End list
          .frame(minWidth: 350, maxWidth: 350)
          .onAppear {
            self.selection = 0
        }

      } // End NavigationView
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    } // End HStack
    #endif

  } // End some View
} // End ContentView

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WorkingDog, I try your elegante code with a very simple code to change the text color depending on the Target... but the text stays blue on both target and does not go red on MacOS!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

      #if os(macOS)
      return monText.foregroundColor(Color.red)
      #elseif os(iOS)
       return monText.foregroundColor(Color.blue)
      #endif
      }

  var monText: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: you are correct. I've edited my answer. I should have used: #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works fine. The project is an iOS Target with iOS, iPad and Mac selected that uses macCatalyst.

Answer (score 0):

More elegant, appropriate and reusable approach to conditionally add modifier would be by using `EmptyModifier()`.

```
We can use the empty modifier to switch modifiers at compile time during development.
```

Let's say you want apply frame modifier based on OS Conditions, First create a custom `ViewModifier` like so:

```
struct CustomFrame: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
            content
            .frame(width: 120)
        }
}
```

Now create an `instance` of CustomFrame `ViewModifier` and add conditions as per the business logic:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var frameModifier: some ViewModifier {
        #if os(iOS)
        return CustomFrame()
        #elseif os(macOS)
        return EmptyModifier() // <- EmptyModifier()
        #endif
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            // a bunch of stuff in this stack
        }
        .modifier(frameModifier)  // <- Use custom modifiers like this.
    }
}
```

This will let you add `modifiers` `conditionally` to any view in a `Swifty way`.

Answer (score 0):

I was here exploring other solution. I was bothered to continually apply  *navigationBarTitleDisplayMode*.

I wrote a small modifier / ext to avoid me to change 34 occurrences and cluttering them with *#if os(macOS).. #else..*

(And if in future we have to add another OS.. is a matter of one line in modifier)

```
// MARK: navigationBarTitleDisplayMode

//fake:
#if os(iOS)

public typealias TitleDisplayMode = NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode

#elseif os(macOS)

public enum TitleDisplayMode {
    case automatic
    case inline
    case large
}
#endif


struct PortableNavigationBarTitleDisplayModeViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let mode: TitleDisplayMode
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        
        #if os(iOS)
        content
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(mode)

        #elseif os(macOS)
        content
        // nada. We throw away

        #endif
        
    }
}


public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    
    func portableNavigationBarTitleDisplayMode(_ mode:  TitleDisplayMode) -> some View {
        self.modifier(PortableNavigationBarTitleDisplayModeViewModifier(mode: mode))
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Text("Hello1")
                Text("Hello2")
                Text("Hello3")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Menu")
        }
        .portableNavigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        //.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline) // You wil have: 'navigationBarTitleDisplayMode' is unavailable in macOS
    }
}
```